# On MacOS, Chrome receives focus after unlocking the screen, even if another app is focused

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome

On MacOS/Chrome, after unlocking the screen, my HTML input element receives a focus event, even if Chrome is not the focused application. 
[image: chromeissue]

Moreover, calls to `window.document.hasFocus()` return true, which is totally unexpected, and seems incorrect.

Has anyone else seen this issue, or have an idea as to why it occurs?

Comment: is this w3 schools?

Comment: Yes it is, which makes it even more bizarre

Comment: There might be some bits of code you might not be seeing going on in their side

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that is unlikely, as this also occurs on a standard HTML webpage, as well as in Electron

Comment: whats in the action page.php?